# CSS Padding/Margin rendering differently on iOS versus Android

Tags: android, css, iphone, wordpress, responsive

When checking the homepage for https://www.warehouseappliance.com/ on my iPhone, the categories are overlapping the content above it. Yet on Android the categories are pushed down in the correct position.

This issue doesn't show using emulators, only shows when viewing on an iOS device.

Changing margins and paddings, nothing seems to effect iOS.

I'm unsure what code is causing the issue, site is https://www.warehouseappliance.com/

I expect the category section to not overlap the content on iOS. It should match Android, and the emulators.

Comment: I spent a little bit looking at this in Safari Dev Tools on a Mac. My only guess is one of these selectors may be the culprit: `class="post-40 page type-page status-publish hentry"` - emulators show this element has a height of 272 x 439 which is enough to push the categories below `homeTextHomeBald` - on the device this is not sufficient height. Have you tried maybe specifiying vh here?

Comment: @Elliot, thank you! I added a height of 450px to a class related to those selectors and it seems to have fixed the problem.